# Angulars $http.jsonp() is returning 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, firebase-hosting

I am trying to obtain a .json file from remote server (parse, firebase, amazon).

```
function fetchData(remoteJsonId){
    var url = "https://myAppName.parseapp.com/"+remoteJsonID+"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    console.log(url); //This variable expands to the full domain name which is valid and                       returns success both on wget and the browser
    $http.jsonp(url).then(
        function(resp){

        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err.status) // This posts "404" on console.
        }
    );
}
```

But If I open url in the browser the json file loads. Even if I wget url the json file loads. But through angular it returns a 404 not found. Why is angulars `$http` is returning 404 even though the file exists. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Don't open the same question twice please. Instead update/expand your original question to include a reproduction case. My answer to that question clearly shows how you **can** retrieve JSON data from Firebase through Angular's `$http.jsonp`, so you'll have to provide enough information for us to figure out why yours doesn't work. A jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces your problem goes a long way towards that.

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab in DevTools ? How does the request made by Angular look like ?

Comment: After making JSONP work from the Angular side (in the question linked earlier), it came to light that OP is using Firebase hosting (not Firebase's hierarchical database). JSONP is not supposed on Firebase's Hosting  servers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583064/how-does-http-jsonp-work